# access the return value from boolean ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that returns a boolean. The method on the server works fine. How can I access the return data from this function and use it?

```
var hasCondition = function () {                    
    $.ajax({
        url: "mhqpreinterview.aspx/hasconditions",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ questionNumber: ClickedQuestion }),
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
}

if (hasCondition()) {
//stuff
}
```

Comment: ajax is async, search about callback function or use promises

Comment: Use a global variable.

Comment: Move that condition up into your asynchronous success callback and check the data.YourVariableName. That should get you started.